# i tried to make video editor which takes videos from pc using moviepy python but i am facing some issues and i am new to this

Tags: python, moviepy

```
def open_file():
    
    b_text.set("Loading")
    files = askopenfile(initialdir = ".",parent=root ,title="choose a video",filetype=[("Video Files","*.mp4")])
    if files:
        print("File was loaded")  

    files.without_audio().preview()
```

This is the error i am facing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\felix\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/felix/Desktop/video editor/new.py", line 27, in open_file
    b=Button(root,textvariable=b_text,relief=GROOVE,bg="#232323",fg="white", command=open_file)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'without_audio'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must execute `VideoFileClip` before previewing.

The method `askopenfile` selects a file.
Execute `clip = VideoFileClip(file.name)` for creating `VideoFileClip` object.
Then you can execute `clip.without_audio().preview()`.

For more details see: [MoviePy – Previewing a Video Clip](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moviepy-previewing-a-video-clip/).

---

When executing the code, I was getting an error message:

> clip.preview requires Pygame installed

I has to install [pygame](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/).

---

Here is a code sample for selecting and previewing a video file:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from moviepy.editor import *
   
file = askopenfile(initialdir = ".", title="choose a video", filetype=[("Video Files","*.mp4")])

if file:
    print("File was loaded")

    # https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moviepy-previewing-a-video-clip/
    # Loading video file
    clip = VideoFileClip(file.name)
    
    # previewing the clip at fps = 10
    clip.without_audio().preview(fps=10)
```

---

Note:
Since the example is "stand alone" application, I had to remove the `parent` argument (but you should keep the `parent=root` argument).

Comment: I solved it...anyways thank you so much 